# Pandas DataFrame - Calculated Column based on subset of Columns

Tags: dataframe, pandas, calculated-columns

I have the following  DataFrame

```
                           Qtr Premium      Claim     Rate

Type    Code                                           
A        3                  14  3552.77      100991.7  0.004017
         3                  15  5610.67      105763.6  0.004017
         3                  16  6463.22      107740.6  0.004017
         4                  17  6129.91      106967.7  0.005638
         4                  18  4688.65      103625.6  0.005638
         4                  19  2158.94      97759.66  0.005638
         4                  20  8540.77      89369.72  0.005638
```

I have constant "c"

I'm looking to carry out a row by row calculation that uses the relevant values from Qtr and Rate but updates the values of Premium and Claim.

Example:

```
Premium = Premium / (1+Rate)^(c-Qtr)
Claim = Claim / (1+Rate)^(c-Qtr)
```

In reality I have a lot of columns that I want this calculation carried out on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With df being the name of your dataframe and c is your constant, try:

```
df['Premium'] = df.Premium / ( 1 + df.Rate ) ** (c - df.Qtr)
df['Claim'] = df.Claim / ( 1 + df.Rate ) ** ( c - df.Qtr )
```

Update for comment, I am sure there is a more pythonic way of doing this, but this works:

```
columns = df.columns
subset_cols = columns.drop(['Rate','Qtr'])
for col in subset_cols:
    df[col] = df[col] / ( 1 + df.Rate ) ** (c- df.Qtr)
```

2nd update, you could extract the calculation into a function and carry out the process in a list comprehension

```
def calc(df, col, c):
    df[col] = df[col] / ( 1 + df.Rate ) ** ( c - df.Qtr )
[calc(df, col, c) for col in df.columns.drop(['Rate','Qtr'])]
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Computes the correct values and gets me a working solution. 

Is there a way though to have the the operation occur on all columns, following this pattern. That would mean I could avoid explicitly declaring it for each individual column. 

Lets say I have 22 columns. One is Rate, one is Qtr and the rest metrics like Premium,Claim etc. I don't mind re-setting the index and putting the Qtr and Rate into that. That way assuming we can still use them in the calculation we could then infer that the operation is to occur for ALL columns. Open to ideas.

Comment: This definitely gets me a good working solution. Hopefully someone will come spot this question and come in with a more pythonic or numpyesque operation.

Comment: See updated answer, although I don't think it necessarily reads as nicely, if you start with the DataFrame given I don't think their is a simpler way of doing it. If you think this answers your question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Went with your first update. Reads in a more intuitive way especially for someone new to python. Thankyou.